# Can the monk's Deflect Missiles feature deflect bullets?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk, firearms

Some games do use firearms rules, so this question comes up. Provided the character is aware they are being shot at, can this ability bat aside a bullet?

Comment: Aside: a quick google search indicates that musket fire is faster but still on the same order of magnitude as arrow fire.

Answer (score 24):

### Yes, it is possible.

Here is a [direct tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/862715314064113664) by Jeremy Crawford:

> In my home campaign, we have a monk, and there are firearms.
>    **Deflecting/catching bullets** is high up there when it comes to badass.

The [Deflect Missiles](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#DeflectMissiles-231) feature description says:

> Starting at 3rd level, you can use your reaction to deflect or catch
>   the missile when you are hit by a **ranged weapon attack**. When you do
>   so, the damage you take from the attack is reduced by 1d 10 + your
>   Dexterity modifier + your monk level. If you reduce the damage to 0,
>   ***you can catch the missile if it is small enough for you to hold in one
>   hand and you have at least one hand free***.

While J. Crawford's tweet relates to a a potential house rule*, the description of the Deflect Missiles ability simply states a *ranged weapon attack*. This means that **any** ranged weapon attack, which a firearm most certainly falls under. It is considered a ranged martial weapon (DMG pg. 268).

The other requirement is for the projectile to be *small enough for you to hold in one hand* and *that you have a free hand to catch it*. A bullet is definitely small enough to hold in one hand.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61088/discussion-on-answer-by-arcemius-can-the-deflect-missiles-ability-deflect-bullet).

Comment: Catching a shotgun blast would be interesting.  Although, I guess it would have a large enough spread to be larger than could be held in one hand.